# Why can't I set permission 700 to uploads folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, upload

I have read this [Setting correct permissions for uploading files](https://superuser.com/questions/581194/setting-correct-permissions-for-uploading-files) and have already changed the ownership to the user that is running Apache.

I have a directory named "uploads" and I'm trying to set its permissions to 700. As I understand, this means that it will give read, write, and execute permissions for the owner user only. However, is not possible to upload files with this permission, it only allows it when I set executable permission to "other" users (e.g. 701 works fine). Is there something I'm missing or should take into account?

Comment: 'X execute" includes the right to enumerate the files in the directory - if you don't set that, nobody can do an 'ls', or do anything that requires processing files inside that dir.

Comment: @Aganju wouldn't the owner user be able to do that?